# Oracle forms 10g developer suite

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I want to deploy the Oracle forms.
I have installed Oracle forms 10g Developer site and created forms.
Now, what i need to install to deploy it and use over web
And how to deploy forms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to do, You'd need to install oracle on a server machine, and all related services in order to run forms, please find a full guide here:

[Fusion Middleware Installation Guide for Oracle Forms and Reports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24269_01/doc.11120/e23960/install.htm#FRINS101)

Good luck.